# 入れ子モデルで無限ループをさけながら、深い階層まで表示させるテーブルを作りたい（一部コードあり）

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

以下のコードのようなテーブルを作ろうとしております。 
(親のIDとアイテム名を表示させるテーブル)

その実装にいわゆる入れ子モデル？の方式で実装を進めております。

アイテム
-サブアイテム
--サブアイテム
---サブアイテム

という風に階層を深くしていくテーブルを実装中で、コードは以下になります。
以下のコードで深い階層のサブアイテムも表示させようとすると、childrenのループの中に、さらにループをたして、その中にさらにループを・・・とやっていくと、できなくはないですが、もう少し上手な方法ができないかと考えております。

while文で試して見たのですが、無限ループにかかってしまい、上手く出来ませんでした。

どなたかやり方が分かる方はいらっしゃいますでしょうか？
宜しくお願いします。

※item.childrenでのchildrenはアイテムのprent_idを見て、該当するサブアイテムを複数返します。

```
tbody
  -@items.each do |item|
    tr
      td #{item.parent_id}
      td #{item.name}
      td
        tbody
          -item.children.each do |child_item|
            tr
              td #{child_item.parent_id}
              td #{child_item.name}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

似たようなサンプルアプリを作ってみました。
partial viewを使えばうまくいくと思います。

### 出力結果

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

### Model

```
class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :parent_group, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: 'parent_group_id'
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Group', foreign_key: 'parent_group_id'
end
```

### seeds.rb

```
Group.destroy_all

parent_1 = Group.create!(name: '親1')
parent_2 = Group.create!(name: '親2')

child_1_1 = parent_1.children.create!(name: '子1-1')
child_1_2 = parent_1.children.create!(name: '子1-2')

child_2_1 = parent_2.children.create!(name: '子2-1')

grand_child_1_1_1 = child_1_1.children.create!(name: '孫1-1-1')
```

### Controller

```
def index
  @groups = Group.where(parent_group_id: nil)
end
```

### index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing Groups</h1>

<%= render 'groups', groups: @groups %>
```

### _groups.html.erb

```
<dl>
  <% groups.each do |group| %>
    <dt><%= group.name %></dt>
    <dd>
      <% if children = group.children.presence %>
        <%= render 'groups', groups: group.children %>
      <% else %>
        子グループがありません。
      <% end %>
    </dd>
  <% end %>
</dl>
```

### HTML

```
<dl>
  <dt>親1</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>子1-1</dt>
      <dd>
        <dl>
          <dt>孫1-1-1</dt>
          <dd>子グループがありません。 </dd>
        </dl>
      </dd>
      <dt>子1-2</dt>
      <dd>子グループがありません。 </dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
  <dt>親2</dt>
  <dd>
    <dl>
      <dt>子2-1</dt>
      <dd>子グループがありません。 </dd>
    </dl>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: partial viewを使う方法でできるんですね。べんきょうになりました。
私の環境下でも実現できました。
実装の幅が広がった気がします。ありがとうございました！